# What can I call classes that are managing entities?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have some classes around my domain entities that provide some service over entity to entity and other classes, such as managing association instances (loading and querying), Copying entity, Tracking changes, Serialization, and the like. 
They all have a property of type entity. These classes act like a wrapper for entity, and add some behavior and state on top of it.

I maintain references to instances of these classes in entity. I want to know what kind of pattern match this design and what should I call these classes (service, manager or controller, ...)?

For example consider following class:

```
public class CopyService
    {
        public IEntity Entity { get; set; }

        public IEntity Copy(bool includeChildren, Predicate<IEntity> childrenPredicate)
        {

        }

        public IEntity Copy(Predicate<IEntity> childsPredicate)
        {
        }

        public IEntity Copy(bool includeChildren)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe Repository

Comment: can you make an example?

Comment: Maybe Active record pattern

Comment: @rascio I added an example

Comment: @DeepakKumarTP I don't think so.

Comment: @JanMuncinsky would you clarify how it matches Active record?

Comment: ..."An object carries both data and behavior."...https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html... You said, you have reference to service in your entity...

Comment: @JanMuncinsky I have decomposed behavior and related data in order to keep class responsibility clear. These classes will add too many behavior to entity if I move them back to entity and violates SRP.

Comment: if you separate data and behaviour, then you should remove the "domain-driven-design" tag from your question.

Comment: without knowing your motivation, I must say I don't like your pattern. If you really need to have those funcionalities coded outside your entity implementation, then at least make it stateless.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher In fact these behaviors are somehow utility behavior and most of them maintain state which are specific to each instance of entity. But these behavior and state are not business concerned.
For some types of entity, some behavior also may be overridden.

Comment: @EasterBunnyBugSmasher These classes act like a wrapper for entity, and add some behavior and state on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that these are behaviors of entities and probably you compose these behaviors with the entity that can use it, in my opinion a possibile name is "**Behavior**" but also **service** can be the name (thinking to domain services);

Comment: I like the "Behavior" but not the "Service". They are not like Domain Services.

Comment: @MohammadaminKhayat well, then "behavior" could be the correct suffix